# jquery - Sortable Interaction not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm working in a ASP.NET MVC 3 application, and I'm trying to use jQuery's Sortable. I already have a jQuery DatePicker working. In my View I have the following code:

```
<link href=@Url.Content("~/Content/jquery_css/jquery.ui.all.css") rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src=@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.ui.core.js") type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src=@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.ui.datepicker.js") type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src=@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.ui.widget.js") type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src=@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.ui.mouse.js") type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src=@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.ui.sortable.js") type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Here is the initializer code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#DateBegin").datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy" }).val();
        $("#DateEnd").datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy" }).val();
        $("#MenuPages").sortable("enable");
    }); 
</script>
```

The DatePicker work seamlessly. Here is the code:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Search history</legend>
        <p>
            Begin: <br />
            <input type="text" id="DateBegin" name="DateBegin" value="" />
            <br />
            End: <br />
            <input type="text" id="DataEnd" name="DataEnd" value=""/>
            <br />
        </p>
    <button>Search</button>
</fieldset>
```

But the Sortable does not work. The code:

```
<ul name="MenuPages" id="MenuPages">
    <li id="page_1">Home</li>
    <li id="page_2">Blog</li>
    <li id="page_3">About</li>
    <li id="page_4">Contact</li>
</ul>
```

I downloaded the DatePicker about a month ago, and downloaded the Sortable now. I put the `jquery.ui.mouse.js`, `jquery.ui.widget.js` and `jquery.ui.sortable.js` in the session. I also replaced `jquery.ui.core.js`.

I don't know if it was necessary, I also copied `jquery-ui-1.8.19.custom.js` to the session (there's also `jquery-ui-1.8.11.js` and `jquery-ui-1.8.11.min.js` there).

Don't know where the source of the error could be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

`$("#MenuPages").sortable("enable");`

try

`$("#MenuPages").sortable();`

to initialize the sortable.

Comment: @LucasReis happens to the best of us.